# How to convert json date record with javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

I pull data from a database and output JSON. Once of the items pulls a date entered in this format `2018-06-25`

I tried this:

```
var date = new Date(element.rundate).toString().substring(0,15);
```

However the output subtracts a day like this `Sun Jun 24 2018`

Anyone know how to correct?

Comment: welcome to the problem with timezones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use moment.js or

```
const date = new Date(element.rundate)
result = date.getFullYear() + "-" + date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`, JavaScript will [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) it as an [ISO 8601 date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), so it will assume it's `UTC 00:00`.

However, if the date format is `yyyy/mm/dd` or `mm-dd-yyyy` it will use local time, according to the [`RFC 2822`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3):

> The date and time-of-day SHOULD express local time.

Therefore, replacing dashes `-` with slashes `/` will do the trick. Alternatively, you can also split the different parts of the date and create a new date string representation with the format `mm-dd-yyyy`, but I think the previous approach is more concise and cleaner:

```js
// Original date:
const dashes = '2018-06-25';

// With slashes instead of dashes:
const slashes = dashes.replace(/-/g, '\/');

// mm-dd-yyyyinstead of dd-mm-yyyy:
const [ year, month, day ] = dashes.split('-');
const monthDayYear = `${ month }-${ day }-${ year }`;

// Output:
console.log(`${ dashes } => ${ new Date(dashes) }`);
console.log(`${ dashes } => ${ slashes } => ${ new Date(slashes) }`);
console.log(`${ dashes } => ${ monthDayYear } => ${ new Date(monthDayYear) }`);
```